# Remove React tags in HTML with Python expressions

Tags: python, html, regex

I am trying to use Python regular expression to remove some react tags in a HTML file. Part of the HTML file looks like this below.

```
<span data-reactid="57">Price/Book</span><!-- react-text: 58 --> <!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 59 -->(mrq)<!-- /react-text --><sup aria-label="KS_HELP_SUP_undefined" data-reactid="60"></sup></td><td class="Fz(s) Fw(500) Ta(end)" data-reactid="61">8.36</td>
```

And my Python regular expression code looks like this below.

```
cleandUpCode = re.sub(r'<!-- react-text: \d{1,2,3} -->', '', sourceCode)
```

sourceCode variable contains the raw HTML source code that has all the react junk in it. I can run the code and it would execute. But when I pipe the output to a file and check it, all the react junk tags are still there.

Could someone help?

Thank a lot in advance.

-frank

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change \d{1,2,3} to \d{1,3} for your code. The quantifier {1,3} repeats the previous item 1 to 3 times.

> Regex Quantifier: http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html#quantifiers

Check this: [Python Regex Demo](http://rextester.com/LVBL2621)

**Update:**
If you want to remove all the `react-text` except the specific one, use: `<!--[^>]*/?react-text[^>]*-->` instead.

Comment: Thanks John. I tried that but when I opened the updated HTML file, the react tags are still there. I must be doing something wrong besides the quantifier.

Comment: Hi Frank, the regex `<!-- react-text: \d{1,3} -->` can only match specified string : <!-- react-text: xxx -->.

Comment: Thanks again John. '<!--[^>]*/?react-text[^>]*-->' removed all the react tags. But I don't understand why '<!-- react-text: \d{1,2} -->' (I changed to 2 numbers) didn't work since I knew there are react tags match exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to only include the greatest number of digits that could occur in the react tags. Also, to remove both instances of `react` (with and without digits) you can add `|` to attempt to match one or the other:

```
cleandUpCode = re.sub(r'<!-- react-text: \d{1,3} -->|<!-- /react-text -->', '', sourceCode)
```

Output:

```
<span data-reactid="57">Price/Book</span> (mrq)
<sup aria-label="KS_HELP_SUP_undefined" data-reactid="60">
 </sup></td><td class="Fz(s) Fw(500) Ta(end)" data-reactid="61">8.36</td>
```

Comment: Thanks Ajax1234. John also mentioned that I should remove the 2 in the middle. But when I tried that code. It still don't remove the react tags from the HTML. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to go trough an HTML document with python, it's easier and more practical to use a library called BeautifulSoup 4.

You can download it from: `https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4` ,
Or, you can use "Pip" to download it by writing `pip install beautifulsoup4` in your command line. Than include it to project `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`

Now you should just extract the text from it, if that's what you want to do.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    with open "text.txt" as text:
    str = '<span data-reactid="57">Price/Book</span><!-- react-text: 58 --> <!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 59 -->(mrq)<!-- /react-text --><sup aria-label="KS_HELP_SUP_undefined" data-reactid="60"></sup></td><td class="Fz(s) Fw(500) Ta(end)" data-reactid="61">8.36</td>'
    soup = BeautifulSoup(str, 'lxml')
    soup = soup.get_text()
    text.write(str(soup))
```

Comment: Hi almarc, thank you for sharing BeautifulSoup. Your code did strip away all the react tags. Thanks! But I had difficulty to target the 8.36 (Price/Book) value after that since the get_text() function seems also remove all the HTML structure. I will read more about BeautifulSoup and see whether there is a way to target the numerical value for Price/Book.

Comment: If you receive an answer to your question which solves the problem (Like the one above from John), please accept it by pressing the check mark below votes counter.